docker-composer.yaml: no such file or directory(file exists)
The file exitst. However when I try to run docker-compose it couldn't find the file.
stat $(pwd)/docker-compose.yml


docker-compose -f $(pwd)/docker-composer.yaml up


In additional when I try to run file dirrectly it from the current directory it looks up in snap
docker-compose -f docker-composer.yaml up


OS:

6.5.0-44-generic #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jun 18 14:36:16 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


Your docker compose file is docker-compose.yml not docker-composer.yaml
